# react-testing-library validateDOMNesting Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tbody> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
    in tbody (created by TableBody)
    in TableBody (created by TableBody)
    in TableBody
```

**Question:**

How do I render my `TableBody` component a `table` element, instead of the default `div` that `react-testing-library` uses?

**Supplemental Information:**

I tried passing in options into the `react-testing-library`, `render()`, function but I can't seem to get it working.

I also tried digging around in the `react-testing-library` tests to find examples, but didn't find anything.

```
// react-testing-library

function render(
  ui: React.ReactElement<any>,
  options?: {
    /* You wont often use this, expand below for docs on options */
  },
): RenderResult
```

> **[From the react-testing-library docs](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library#render)**
>
> You wont often need to specify options, but if you ever do, here are
>   the available options which you could provide as a second argument to
>   render.
>
> **container**: By default, `react-testing-library` will create a `div` and
>   append that `div` to the `document.body` and this is where your react
>   component will be rendered. If you provide your own `HTMLElement`
>   container via this option, it will not be appended to the
>   `document.body` automatically.
>
> **baseElement**: If the `container` is specified, then this defaults to
>   that, otherwise this defaults to `document.documentElement`. This is
>   used as the base element for the queries as well as what is printed
>   when you use `debug()`.

My testing code using Jest:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from "react-testing-library";

import TableBody from "../TableBody";
import listingDataMock from "../__mocks__/TableBody-listing-data";

afterEach(cleanup);

describe("TableBody", () => {
  test("Snapshot", () => {
    //Arrange--------------
    const listingData = listingDataMock;
    const tableBodyKey = "candidateId";

    const props = {
      listingData,
      tableBodyKey
    };

    const { container } = render(<TableBody {...props} />);

    //Assert---------------
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: `render(<table><TableBody {...props} /></table>)` is not an option for you?

Comment: @Tholle Nice =) That does work! But I still hope to figure out how to use the `options` parameter too in the `render` function.

Comment: Alright. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/blob/2baff576ad8214bf375b2491f51d09dc1e7294a2/src/index.js#L7-L11) it looks like `container` will be `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))` unless you specify it yourself. Have you tried `render(<TableBody {...props} />, { container: document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table')) }`?

Comment: @Tholle Ah, that works! Thanks! Now `render(<table><TableBody {...props} /></table>)` actually looks a lot less verbose for team members to grok the test =p If you add that as an answer, I'll select it. Thanks!

Comment: Hehe, I agree with you. Might look a bit more readable with `const table = document.createElement('table'); document.body.appendChild(table);  render(<TableBody {...props} />, { container: table });`

Comment: @Tholle are you able to add “react-testing-library” as a tag to your answer? New SO tags require a reputation of 1500. I wanted to tag my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the default `react-testing-library` container and wrap your component with a `table`:

```
const { container } = render(<table><TableBody {...props} /></table>);
```

You could also create a `table` element and use that as container by passing it to the options:

```
const table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(table);
const { container } = render(<TableBody {...props} />, { container: table });
```